# run mongo db with docker and access it using robo 3T

Tags: mongodb, docker

I am trying to run mongo db using docker with following command,

```
sudo docker run -v /var/lib/mongo:/data/db -v /home/naggappan/mongo.conf:/etc/mongo.conf -p 27017:27017 mongo -f /etc/mongo.conf
```

And I get the following error in syslog messages,

```
May  2 10:19:42 d-mongo-db-dev.india.ks.net kernel: overlayfs: upper fs needs to support d_type. This is an invalid configuration.
May  2 10:19:43 d-mongo-db-dev.india.ks.net kernel: overlayfs: upper fs needs to support d_type. This is an invalid configuration.
May  2 10:19:43 d-mongo-db-dev.india.ks.net kernel: overlayfs: upper fs needs to support d_type. This is an invalid configuration.
May  2 10:19:43 d-mongo-db-dev.india.ks.net kernel: docker0: port 1(vethef7446b) entered blocking state
May  2 10:19:43 d-mongo-db-dev.india.ks.net kernel: docker0: port 1(vethef7446b) entered disabled state
May  2 10:19:43 d-mongo-db-dev.india.ks.net kernel: device vethef7446b entered promiscuous mode
May  2 10:19:43 d-mongo-db-dev.india.ks.net kernel: IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): vethef7446b: link is not ready
May  2 10:19:43 d-mongo-db-dev.india.ks.net kernel: docker0: port 1(vethef7446b) entered blocking state
May  2 10:19:43 d-mongo-db-dev.india.ks.net kernel: docker0: port 1(vethef7446b) entered forwarding state
May  2 10:19:43 d-mongo-db-dev.india.ks.net kernel: docker0: port 1(vethef7446b) entered disabled state
May  2 10:19:43 d-mongo-db-dev.india.ks.net systemd: Started libcontainer container 7adf209c744c2753d46d6bcbe5623d6f0a56ac9bb71cc61922a056563daf4552.
May  2 10:19:43 d-mongo-db-dev.india.ks.net systemd: Starting libcontainer container 7adf209c744c2753d46d6bcbe5623d6f0a56ac9bb71cc61922a056563daf4552.
May  2 10:19:43 d-mongo-db-dev.india.ks.net kernel: SELinux: mount invalid.  Same superblock, different security settings for (dev mqueue, type mqueue)
May  2 10:19:43 d-mongo-db-dev.india.ks.net kernel: IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): vethef7446b: link becomes ready
May  2 10:19:43 d-mongo-db-dev.india.ks.net kernel: docker0: port 1(vethef7446b) entered blocking state
May  2 10:19:43 d-mongo-db-dev.india.ks.net kernel: docker0: port 1(vethef7446b) entered forwarding state
May  2 10:19:43 d-mongo-db-dev.india.ks.net dockerd-current: time="2018-05-02T10:19:43.615971849Z" level=error msg="containerd: deleting container" error="exit status 1: \"container 7adf209c744c2753d46d6bcbe5623d6f0a56ac9bb71cc61922a056563daf4552 does not exist\\none or more of the container deletions failed\\n\""
May  2 10:19:43 d-mongo-db-dev.india.ks.net kernel: docker0: port 1(vethef7446b) entered disabled state
May  2 10:19:43 d-mongo-db-dev.india.ks.net kernel: docker0: port 1(vethef7446b) entered disabled state
May  2 10:19:43 d-mongo-db-dev.india.ks.net kernel: device vethef7446b left promiscuous mode
May  2 10:19:43 d-mongo-db-dev.india.ks.net kernel: docker0: port 1(vethef7446b) entered disabled state
May  2 10:19:43 d-mongo-db-dev.india.ks.net dockerd-current: time="2018-05-02T10:19:43.822616722Z" level=warning msg="7adf209c744c2753d46d6bcbe5623d6f0a56ac9bb71cc61922a056563daf4552 cleanup: failed to unmount secrets: invalid argument"
```

But if i just try to rediret port with following command then it works fine,

```
sudo docker run -d -p 27017:27017 mongo
```

And the issue with above command is, mongo db service is not accessable from different machine using UI tools like Robo3T. connection is happning but it fails with following error, as it bind to 127.0.0.1. To change this I need to do input of config file as above and getting error

```
May  2 10:12:13 d-mongo-db-dev.india.ks.net journal: 2018-05-02T10:12:13.025+0000 I NETWORK  [listener] connection accepted from 15.143.35.10:12729 #3 (2 connections now open)
May  2 10:12:13 d-mongo-db-dev.india.ks.net journal: 2018-05-02T10:12:13.036+0000 I NETWORK  [conn3] end connection 15.143.35.10:12729 (1 connection now open)
```

Answer (score 0):

About the file system problems: Mongodb has particular requirements of its OS's file system, as described in [MongoDB Production Notes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/administration/production-notes/). You will need to examine the host system's file system, and change it if necessary to make sure it is compatible with MongoDB.

About making the service accessible from other machines; you will need to review the [bindIp](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/#net.bindIp) configuration setting, to make sure you have it correctly configured to be accessible on external interfaces as well as 127.0.0.1.

Comment: Yes i am using ubuntu centos 7 and it is compatible. The issue here is I need to change the bindIp configurations to access from all machines. But since I use docker I need to provide config file while doing docker run as mentioned above. But Not sure what is the exact command so it is not picking up the config file and using defualt config file always.

Answer (score 0):

i've resolved this problem using docker-compose on this yml (modified from [wesleybliss's gist](https://gist.github.com/wesleybliss/29d4cce863f5964a3eb73c42501d99e4)):

```
version: '2'
services:
mongodb:
    image: mongo:latest
    container_name: "mongodb"
    environment:
      - MONGO_DATA_DIR=/data/db
      - MONGO_LOG_DIR=/dev/null
    volumes:
      - ./data/db:/data/db
    ports:
        - 27017:27017
    command: mongod --smallfiles --logpath=/dev/null # --quiet
```

After run this configuration with 'docker-compose up -d' (sudo if necessary) i have mongodb binded on 0.0.0.0. It can be accessed from external ip.